# if (x) ... gives Reference Error: x is not defined

Tags: javascript

I thought the following would work, whether `x` is declared or assigned a value or not:

```
if (x)
   console.log("x is well defined");
else
   console.log("x is not defined or null or false or 0 ...");
```

However, I am getting (when `x` is nowhere declared in my code):

> x is not defined

Why does this happen?

(This is in a Node.js environment.)

Comment: if x is not declared it will do so (it's an expected behavior), on the other hand `typeof x != "undefined"` doesn't throw any error even if x has not been declared.

Comment: Even with `typeof` you can get Reference Errors, it's better if you rely on static analysis to be honest.

Comment: What exactly do you want to know? You seem to know the solution already: declare `x` in your code when you want to use it.

Comment: I want to do something if x is declared and defined, else do something else. I thought I have also seen this pattern before: `var y = x || "default value";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you not declare x anywhere within scope of if(x) statement ,there will be reference error.

To avoid this , just declare var x; within scope of if(x) statement or its parent scope.

Now if you just declare:

var x;

here value of x is undefined  ,so else part will get executed.

But instead if you defined like:

var x=1;

then if statement will be true and output will be x is well defined

here jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/raushankumar0717/4ozmf7r5/

```js
var x=1;

if(x)
 alert("Defined");
else
  alert("Not Defined");
```

Comment: Thanks everyone for their answers. I was confused with the Javascript in Jade (aka Pug).  In Jade, an undeclared variable can always be tested.  Jade is still Javascript, but apparently undeclared variables are given a default value upon entry to a Jade script.

Answer (score 1):

When `if(x)` is ran, the `x` is checked and not defined, so your if/else means nothing, the JavaScript encounters an **uncaught** error.

You can put it in a try/catch and it will catch the error, but then your if/else will not log anything. Instead you need to do something like:

```
if (typeof x !== 'undefined')
   console.log("x is well defined");
else
   console.log("x is not defined or null or false or 0 ...");
```

Or if you also need to check that "x" is truthy, you can use:

```
if (typeof x !== 'undefined' && x)
   console.log("x is well defined");
else
   console.log("x is not defined or null or false or 0 ...");
```

Comment: I have seen this pattern used often:  `var y = x || "default value";`

Comment: @OldGeezer Same problem. The `x` isn't defined, so error. But that pattern works if `x` is defined, then it checks if x is truthy or not. If it's truthy, then the value of x is assigned to y, such as `"hello world"`. Otherwise the value `"default value"` is assigned.

Comment: What you CAN do however is place something like `var x,y,z;` at the top of the given context, then it's defined. You'll see this sort of thing often: `(function(x){console.log(x||"default value");})();`

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge...
If we see the value of x is 'undefined' so it will give a TypeError!

```
If u see this..
if(typeof x === 'undefined')
    console.log("x is well defined");
```

This will give an output of "x is well defined"
Correct me if i got something else from your question! :)